# Calling dispatch inside redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to integrate [redux-simple-auth](https://github.com/jerelmiller/redux-simple-auth) in my existing reudx API. My old implementation used the native `fetch` and I added headers etc.. This new module provides a fetch replacement however it returns a redux action and am having a bit of a struggle figuring out how to set things up.

My store:

```
function configureStore (initialState) {
  const middlewares = [
    authMiddleware,  // This is from rediux-simple-auth
    apiMiddleware, // My own middleware
    thunk

  ]

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares), getInitialAuthState({ storage }))
  )
}
```

My middleware simplified:

```
import { fetch } from 'redux-simple-auth'
export default store => next => action => {      
  ...
  next(my start action...)
  return store.dispatch(fetch(API_ROOT + endpoint, { method }))  
    .then(response => {
       next(my success/fail action...)
    })

}
```

When I run this I can see my start and fail actions in redux inspector but not the fetch one (which does trigger a FETCH one)

If I call `next` instead of `store.dispatch` then it works in the sense that it tiggers the action but it does not return a promise I cannot get results.

How can I fix this flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`next` is not `dispatch`. Try this:

```
export default ({dispatch}) => next => action => ...
```

Use `dispatch` to dispatch your *new action* and use `next(action)` to pass the *original action* to the next middleware.

Comment: I found that my issue was the redux auth code was failing and never triggering the FETCH action which was throwing me off.